# how you remove the second node from a linear linked list c++

Tags: c++

this coding was to delete the first node, but I guess if I learned to remove the second I will know how to remove the first so here is what I did to remove the first node which now replaces the value with 0.

```
    void removeFirst ( node * head)
  {
     node * temp = head;
      head = head -> next;
      delete temp;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried and illustrating what isn't working and [read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *"replaces the value with 0."* - there is no mention of 0 anywhere in that code

Comment: your `removeFirst` wont remove anything, as you pass the pointer by value .`head = head->next` has no effect outside of that function, though `delete temp` deletes your current `head` so you are basically corrupting your list

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I TRIED TO DO  node * temp = head;
 66     temp = head -> data;
 67     head = head -> next;
 68     delete head;
 69     head = temp;

Comment: Single linked list or double linked list?

Answer (score 0):

You should look up linked lists in your favorite data structures book.
Let's assume that `head` points to the start of the list and each node has a `next` field.

```
// Get the pointer to the second node.
Node * p_second_node = head->next;

// Copy the second node's link to the head node's link:
if (p_second_node)
{
  head->next = p_second_node->next;
}

// Finally, delete the second node:
delete p_second_node;
```

You should always check if the pointer to the second node is `nullptr`.  Deferencing a NULL pointer is undefined behavior.

**Edit 1 -- Deleting the first node**
Here are the steps for deleting the first, head node:

```
Node * p_first_node = head;
if (head)
{
  head = p_first_node->next;
  delete p_first_node;
}
```

Note:  in both cases above, a temporary pointer is created to point to the node to be deleted.  This is required because when the links are altered, the node would not be accessible and a memory leak generated.  The temporary pointer allows for deleting the node after the links are changed.